# gdbserver 7.9 missing from http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gdb/gdb-7.9.tar.gz

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb, gnu, gdbserver

I downloaded the gdb-7.9 tarbell from :

http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gdb/gdb-7.9.tar.gz

After running running configure/make/make install , I notice that the gdbserver binary is missing :

[root@machine bin]# ls

gcore  gdb

Whereas if i download the 7.8 tarfile from http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gdb/gdb-7.8.tar.gz and run configure/make/make install  , gdbserver is there :

[root@machine bin]# ls

gcore  gdb  gdbserver

I have the following questions :

Is gdbserver purposely missing from gdb 7.9 ?

If so , will it be added at a later date ?

Is gdb 7.9 compatible with older versions of gdb server ?

Thanks for your help,

Comment: `gdbserver` is still available in 7.9.  I would recommend doublechecking the output of the compile for an error message.

Comment: Thank you for the the tip , I believe something went wrong during make install  but it failed silently

Answer (score 1):

> After running running configure/make/make install , I notice that the gdbserver binary is missing

The `gdbserver` binary is present for me on Linux/x86_64 using system GCC.

It may not be installed if you have an unsupported OS, or are cross-compiling. Unfortunately you didn't provide any details of which OS you are building on, and which compiler you are using.

> Is gdb 7.9 compatible with older versions of gdb server

In general, GDB never assumes anything about the remote system it is talking to (there may not even be a gdbserver, but instead a gdb stub for some embedded OS), and always negotiates supported capabilities by querying for them.

Comment: Thank you for the the info, I believe something went wrong during make install step but it failed silently